# Empty image on image.save

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application where I need to save a modified image to a new bitmap, which in this case is PNG. Recently it saves without complaining but when I look on the output files, it contains no data, and there is no preview, only the standard windows icon. No error is thrown and I've confirmed the data was drawn correctly by putting the image to an existing pictureBox in the application.

Why this behaviour?

```
pBN = new PictureBox();
Sonique QF = bmps.Pop();
Bitmap X  =new Bitmap(QF.Picture);

this.Controls.Add(pBN);
pictureBox1.Image = X;
Thread.Sleep(300);

pictureBox1.Image.Save(Program.GetAppString()+"\\playlists\\"+QF.LinkString.Replace(":","__")+".png");
```

Comment: My guess is that the alpha channel is all zero.

Comment: @Timbo - without the code it is just a guess. It could be anything - such as forgetting to flush the buffer.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(300);` <- what is that supposed to do? Doesn't make any sense to me to sleep like this

Comment: First I believe there was some delay for rendering image data or so..

Comment: How I do save a bitmap image to PNG? It's what I'm supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the `X` variable itself.